# Conditional Probability over all conditions

Tags: probability

Assume that there is an event such as $D:\{1,2, ...,i\}$ and a set of observations $O_{1:t}$. My question is, based on Bayes law is it correct to assume:

$
P(O_{1:t}) = \sum_{j \in \{1,2, ...,i\}} P(O_{1:t}|D=j)
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely. If $\{D_n:n=1,2,\ldots,i\}$ is a partition of the sample space then by the law of total probability we can write
\begin{align}
P(A) = \sum_{n}P(A,D_n)
\end{align}
or alternatively
\begin{align}
P(A) =\sum_nP(A|D_n)P(D_n)
\end{align}
(don't forget the $P(D_n)$ term)

Comment: Tnx, I know that something was missing